# Custom checkbox field to change the customer group

Tags: custom, checkbox

I have created a custom check box field in billing.phtml(Magento 1.9.2.1), i want to assign customer group based on this field (i,e.. if the field is check the customer will be in one customer group and if the field is not checked the customer will be in another customer group.). how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do by observing customer save before event.

```
        <customer_save_before>
            <observers>
                <unique_customer_save>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>customer_save_before</method>
                </unique_customer_save>
            </observers>
        </customer_save_before>
```

Replace `Namespace_Module` with your module name.

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer
{    
    public function customer_save_before($observer)
    {
        $group_id = 3; //Change this to your id
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
        $customer->setCustomerGroupId($group_id);
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r( $customer->getData() );
        Mage::log( $customer->getData() , null, 'customer_Before.log');        
    }

}
```

Change `$group_id` value to your value.